# How can I decompress an archive file having .zst or tar.zst?

Tags: compression, archive, zstd

Suppose I have two files:

- `file1.zst`
- `file2.tar.zst`

How can I decompress these files in terminal?

Comment: People looking for a pythonic way, here is the tool which can help you in decompressing .zst files on windows OS. https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/

Comment: On **Windows**: https://peazip.github.io/zstandard-compression-utility.html

Comment: this question is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406503/839601)

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The extention .zst means that the archive is compressed by zstd.

- https://github.com/facebook/zstd

The tar command has an option -I (--use-compress-program) to specify a command for compression/decompression.

You can use it as follows.

```
$ tar --use-compress-program=unzstd -xvf archive.tar.zst
```

Comment: tar (child): zstd: Cannot exec: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1271772 Might not be installed. For Debian, `sudo apt-get install zstd`. `yum` or whatever for other distros.

Comment: Is there a way without installing anything extra? I don't have sudo permission on the server. I would rather not have to scp the file to a different machine, uncompress, then transfer back.

Comment: @user1271772 you could build it from source

Comment: @SuiciDoga: Good idea. Though it's unfortunate we can't decompress these files more "natively".

Comment: @user1271772 if you want to uncompress natively you could install the package

Comment: @SuiciDoga: I just explained that I don't have sudo permission. So as you say, the only way is to install from source, but that is not "native". It would be nice if the Linux distribution had this program just like it comes with the programs "grep" and "vi"

Comment: @user1271772 ubuntu is going to use zstd by default in the future

Comment: The `-I` or `--use-compress-program` argument only works if I use the equal sign format on the Mac. So, `tar -I=/usr/local/sbin/zstd -xvf archive.tar.zst` works but the one given above doesn't. see detail on https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html

Comment: This tar command also works fine in `Git-Bash`, if you are on Windows.

Comment: If you want to extract you have to select `unzstd`. The following worked for me: `tar --use-compress-program=unzstd -xvf archive.tar.zst`

Comment: If you're `tar` has builtin zstd support you can just use `tar axvf archive.tar.zst` which will autodetect the compression format.

Comment: How do I decompress this file type on Windows?

Comment: @user1271772 If by natively you mean without explicitly running a compiler or `make` you can create a local python environment e.g with `virtualenv`, `pip install zstandard` and write your own `unzstd` as `import zstandard; import sys; zstandard.ZstdDecompressor().copy_stream(sys.stdin.buffer, sys.stdout.buffer)` (not tested, following Jonathan's answer below).

Comment: My GNU `tar` (version 1.30, supplied by Ubuntu 20.04) supports the `--zstd` flag to support archives in zstd format. It requires the `zstd` executable.

Comment: slight modification. I did'nt have `unzstd` but have `zstd`. So did this in two steps:
zstd -d openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst` then `tar xvf openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-2-x86_64.pkg.tar` then copied libssl.o and libcrypto.o in /usr/lib64 appened with .1.1 in the end, then created symlinks to the original name.

Answer (score 138):

Decompress it in Terminal.

```
unzstd yourfilename.zst
```

I know there aren't many resources available but I found this here: http://manpages.org/zstd

Comment: you have to install the package `zstd` for the unzstd command. note, that it has problems with a colon in the package name, so rename those packages beforehand

Comment: @rubo77
For me, it works with a colon, must be updated or something. But what I am guessing is that your shell is not working and maybe quote it with `''` or `""`, or you can just escape it with \.

Answer (score 23):

If you have a standard cmake + gcc build stack:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/zstd.git
cd zstd/build/cmake
cmake .
make
./programs/zstd -d /path/to/file.zst
```

Comment: as someone without root permissions, this answer was amazingly helpful and complete. Cannot thank you enough

Answer (score 13):

On macOS Mojave 10.14.3, I was unable to specify the compression algorithm using the -I flag. Doing it this way worked for me;

Install zstd using brew if you don't already have it installed.

1. Decompress from .zst: `unzstd filename.tar.zst` or `zstd -d filename.tar.zst`. `filename.tar` will be created.
2. List compressed archive: `tar tf filename.tar`.
3. Extract the compressed archive: `tar xf filename.tar`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mac 10? 10.0 was a long, long time ago, but Zstandard is a recent algorithm.

Comment: I am not clear on what you meant but zstd is a utility that implements the zstandard compression algorithm.

Comment: In your post, you said Mac 10. I think you meant to say something along the lines of macOS 10.15, Catalina or something to that effect. OS X 10.0 Cheetah was released in 2001: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Mac_OS_X_10.0_Cheetah

Comment: Thanks. Updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Download the [Python library](https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/) and then you can use Python like following:

```
import zstandard as zstd
dctx = zstd.ZstdDecompressor()
with open(submission_path_read, 'rb') as ifh, open(submission_path_save, 'wb') as ofh:
    dctx.copy_stream(ifh, ofh, write_size=65536)
```

Comment: no need to use the python wrapper for zstandard here, and this python script starts with an `elif` so will not even run...

Comment: How will you decompress on windows?

Comment: Fair enough. Still, this is not a functioning python script (starts with `elif` poorly described variables, leaves out some sort of file-path selection mechansim?, …). On top of that, from what I can tell, this would just decompress to a `.tar` archive which is a solution to only half of the poster's problem.

Comment: That's why there is ... The code is not complete. OP question's title was How to decompress. I answered that.

Comment: This is useful, saved me further trouble adding a package to git-for-windows (MSYS2) avoiding all manner of hoops.   And it works on Windows.  Used `python -m pip install zstandard` to install the module.

Comment: Thanks @EdRandall. I don't know why people would downvote it tho :)

Comment: It will decompress it to tar. Then I used 7zip to decompress it to normal folder.

Comment: this was useful to me. especially the streaming part

Comment: Worked for me on windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I found some of these files in the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) downloads. After I installed Anaconda, I was downloading additional packages. The downloaded packages in my Anaconda download directory were zip files (without the .zip extension), but they had these `.tar.zst` files inside them. That led me to stack**overflow** to figure out what they were, which led me to this question. If you're in the same boat, then Anaconda also supplies the answer.

It turns out that the `zstd` and `unzstd` executables are also installed by the Anaconda installer, so they should be available at the command line if you're in your Anaconda environment.