# How do you uncompress a zstd file in python?

Tags: python, zstandard

How can I decompress a zstd file in Windows or with Python?

Comment: This question has already been answered over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355277/how-can-i-decompress-an-archive-file-having-tar-zst

Comment: I was able to get it. I have added the answer

Comment: You're welcome!!

Comment: Answers should not be edited into questions. If you want to add your own answer, use the "Add an Answer" button -- or, being closed as a duplicate, add your own answer over on the duplicate question. See also [What should I do when the answer to a (closed) question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377643/what-should-i-do-when-the-answer-of-a-closed-question-is-added-to-the-question) on [meta].

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55074977/2865368